# Why is the cursor in google charts off when I resize the chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[Here is a picture of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U36da.png)

And here is the JS code:

```
<script>
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Days Back', 'Volume'],
  <?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < $volinterval - $period; $i++) {
    echo "['" . $daysforcharts[$i + 1] . "' ," . number_format($histvolArray[$i + 2], 4)*100 . "], ";
  }
  ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
    fontName: 'Roboto',
    width: 1200,
    height: 400,
    explorer: {
        keepInBounds: 'true',
        axis: 'horizontal',
        maxZoomOut: 1,
        zoomDelta: 1.02, // lowest value is 1 (which doesn't move)
    },
      hAxis: {
        direction: -1,
      format: 'yyyy/MM/dd' },
    backgroundColor:  { fill: 'transparent' },
    lineWidth: 1,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
      vAxis: {
      logScale: 'true',
      minValue: 'auto',
      baselineColor: 'transparent',
      gridlineColor: 'transparent',
      gridlines: { color: 'transparent' },
      }

    };
   var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('histvol_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

The cursor is always on point when the width is 1000px, but when I resize it up or down it is off like in the picture.

Edit: The cursor would be to the left of the dot. Sorry. I forgot screenshots don't capture them.

Edit 2: The answer to this is to not center it, and make sure that your div size is the same as your chart area.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you're probably not looking into this question any more, but I just stumbled across it because I was having the same issue.

The issue was caused by adding padding to the Chart's div. I had added 20 pixels of padding to the left, which I'm assuming is the exact offset of the cursor compared to the data points being highlighted. Once I removed that padding, everything worked fine.